# Is there a way to instrument multi-dex Android apk for code coverage?

Tags: android, testing, code-coverage, android-multidex, dynamic-analysis

Good afternoon, I could use some help.
I am looking for a tool that allows to automatically instrument a multi-dex Android application, so to generate code coverage reports at the end of dynamic analysis. At the moment I have tested two tools namely [COSMO](https://github.com/H2SO4T/COSMO) and [ACVTOOL](https://github.com/pilgun/acvtool). The way these tools work from what I understand is that they go to insert 'flags' within the code of the app so that when the dynamic analysis "touches" that flag located in a certain part of code, it goes to generate a coverage.

Unfortunately, however, the problem with these two tools is that they can only be used on single-dex applications, so my question is this:
**Could you tell me if there are any tools that can instrument a multi-dex app so as to generate coverage after doing dynamic analysis? If so what are they?**
Thank you in advance,
I hope I have been clear and have not missed anything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.